Auto focus on modal open
How to focus to input after modal has been opened? I can't use useRef cause it's not a component and autoFocus is not working, probably cause I have to click button to open this modal
export const payModal = () => {
    confirm({
        icon: " ",
        title: <Input type="text" />,
    })
}


Add an id and access the input by querySelector and focus
export const payModal = () => {
    confirm({
        icon: " ",
        title: <Input id="focus-input" type="text" />,
    })
}
const openModalFn = () => {
    payModal();
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector('#focus-input')?.focus()
    }, 100); // if there's a transition and the input is not available, increase the number to the transition duration
}

